# Circuit powered by 9V battery to output between 3.3-5V

Tags: power-supply, batteries, mosfet, voltage-regulator, low-power

I need to power a device (a LPWAN transmitter) at a voltage of 3.3 to 5V - it can't go below or above these voltages to avoid damaging the device - using a 9V battery. I have solved the problem of regulating down to 5V using a LM317 voltage regulator as shown in the circuit

I wanted to try using a MOSFET to cut-off below 3.5V, but I'm not sure of (1) would this circuit work as I intend and also (2) will the MOSFET drain the battery? This is important the application requires very low power/long battery life

Upon testing lab, I have found that an input of 5V to the LM317 results in 3.5V output, so am I right in thinking choosing a MOSFET with a Gate threshold voltage of 5V this circuit would work as intended?

Note: The 'Final output' with two pins is intended to be two wires, +ve and GND to go to the device that needs power via cables.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUaABp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: NO. There are millions of LDO examples. Did you search? L as in low is relative 40 yr old BJT technology. FET LDOs have a variety of dropouts that can be filtered in Mouser.com.  Can you live with 50% power loss? Why afraid of SMPS?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Hi, I wasn't familiar with LDO circuits or SMPS to be honest, I will look into these further. I tried designing the circuit above as a solution to my problem based on my electronics knowledge (not a great amount) but it looks as if I can just buy a LDO from looking on mouser.com as you suggested

Comment: Your FET will short the regulator output.  The LM317 will probably survive, but you will be discharging your batteries.  Doesn't the FET want to be in series with the load?

Comment: Use "shopping google search" with key words

Comment: Use "shopping google search" with key words. It is always Faster to learn from buy and analyze than design, fail, fix , repeat ... https://www.banggood.com/buy/dc-dc-step-down.html

Comment: You might also wanto to pick some sane resistor values that actually exist in the standard series :)  220R and 680R for example.

Comment: @Lundin those resistor values are the actual values I measured of the resistors I used when making it haha

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thank you for your help I've ordered a LDO regulator that will work for my needs from RS components

Comment: @Froot Ok well it is good practice to look at for example the E12 series when picking resistors for a schematic. When you measure resistance do keep in mind that the particular resistors could have an inaccuracy of 1%, 5% etc.